# Issue with Python Server Returning File On GET

Tags: python, json, rest, python-2.7, simplehttpserver

I created a simple threaded python server, and I have two parameters for format, one is JSON (return string data) and the other is zip.  When a user selects the format=zip as one of the input parameters, I need the server to return a zip file back to the user.  How should I return a file to a user on a do_GET() for my server?  Do I just return the URL where the file can be downloaded or can I send the file back to the user directly?  If option two is possible, how do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I hadn't closed the zipfile object before I tried to return it.  It appeared there was a lock on the file.

To return a zip file from a simple http python server using GET, you need to do the following:

1. Set the header to 'application/zip'

   `self.send_header("Content-type:", "application/zip")`
2. Create the zip file using zipfile module
3. Using the file path (ex: c:/temp/zipfile.zip) open the file using 'rb' method to read the binary information

   `openObj = open( < path > , 'rb')`
4. return the object back to the browser

   `openObj.close()
    del openObj
    self.wfile.write(openObj.read())`

   That's about it. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the file back to the user directly, and add a `Content-Type` header with the correct [media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), such as `application/zip`.

So the header could look like this:

```
Content-Type: application/zip
```

Comment: Ok, I get that, but when you do a json response back to the browser, I am going the following: json.dump(json_template, self.wfile).  This write the text out to the browser.  How do you send back the file object?

Comment: When I do the following:  zipObj = open(zipFile, 'rb')
            self.wfile.write(zipObj.read())
            zipObj.close(), I get the following error: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ZipFile found

Comment: @josh1234 what is `zipFile`? Isn't it already a file instance?

Comment: zipFile is the zipped file path.

Comment: can you do this without django?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you weren't using Django :P. Look at the documentation of the framework you use, you should be able to find it in there.

Comment: I'm using the standard python library.